# how can i build a comment section using react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

i would like to know how to create a comment section using react typescript, I would like the user to put a name and there comment, which is then sent to my firebase project. i would also like if the comments made can be showed right below the comment form, the code below is all I have manage to do, how do I approach this please

```js
import React, { EventHandler, FormEventHandler, useState, FC } from 'react'
import { Box, Button, Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import axios from "axios";

interface FormData {
  user: string;
  comment: string;
  
}


const Comment: FC<FormData> = ({}) => {
  

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({ user: "", comment: ""})

  const handleChange = (e) => {
      const { value, name } = e.target;
      setFormData({ ...formData, [name]: value })
      console.log(formData)
  }

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        const response = await axios.post('/api/comments/index', formData);
}


  return (
    <Box component="form"
                my={3}
            >
                <Grid container
                    direction="row"
                    justify="center"
                    alignItems="flex-end"
                    spacing={2}
                >
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Firstname" variant="outlined" name="firstname" onChange={handleChange} />
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={6}>
                        <TextField 
                        id="filled-multiline-static"
                        label="Comment"
                        multiline
                        rows={4}
                        defaultValue="Share with your artist "
                        variant="filled" onChange={handleChange}/>
                    </Grid>
                    <Box mt={5} display="flex" justifyContent="center">
                      <Box width="70%">
                          <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" fullWidth  onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Comment</Button>
                      </Box>
                    </Box>
                </Grid>
  </Box>
  )

}
export default Comment
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `useState()` returns an array with 2 elements, first is the value and the second is its setter. You're using the first one as a function.

Comment: What did you mean by `const [SetPlayingCurrentSong] = useState()
    const [playingCurrentSong] = useState()`?

Answer (score 5):

Two issues:

1. You're not using [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) correctly
2. You're not providing an initial value for the state, so it will default to `undefined`

`useState` returns a tuple (array) with **two** elements:

- The current value of the state member
- The setter function for the state member

Your code:

```
const [SetPlayingCurrentSong] = useState()
const [playingCurrentSong] = useState()
```

...is only using the first. Your current code is creating and getting the current state of **two** state members, not one. It should be one `useState` call using both elements from the returned tuple:

```
const [playingCurrentSong, SetPlayingCurrentSong] = useState()
```

`playingCurrentSong` will get the current value of the state member, and `SetPlayingCurrentSong` will get the setter for that state member.

If you want an initial value other than `undefined`, pass that value into `useState`:

```
const [playingCurrentSong, SetPlayingCurrentSong] = useState(theInitialValue)
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Side note: Although you can do whatever you like in your own code, the overwhelmingly common convention in JavaScript is that only cosntructor functions are initially-capped. `SetPlayingCurrentSong` should be `setPlayingCurrentSong` (lower case initial "s").

Comment: Thanks going to try implement it now